# How to set Lightning Component SFDX scratch org preferences in project-scratch-def.json?

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code

In the [Scratch Org Definition Configuration Values](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm) documentation I don't see a way to default these settings that we want to make all the time to do Lightning Component development:

- Setup -> Lightning Components -> Enable Debug Mode (want enabled)
- Setup -> Session Settings -> Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance (want disabled so Lightning Components are not cached so changes appear immediately)

So:

1. Is there a way to automatically default them via project-scratch-def.json?
2. Is the scratch org always a clone of some other org that can have stuff manually pre-configured in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is an answer to the browser caching issue now!

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm) now includes "S1EncryptedStoragePref2" which is how you control the browser caching.

So you can include `"disabled": ["S1EncryptedStoragePref2"]` in your org config file.

I still don't know about lightning in debug though.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a January "Technical Enablement for AppExchange Partners (Monthly)" Salesforce webinar (sorry can't find a link to this), the answer is "not yet".